# Did Mail.app once allow messages to be annotated with notes?

Tags: macos, mail.app

I thought I remembered being able to add notes to a message in a pane over the main message (as well as todos). In Lion, I don't see how to do that. I can create individual notes but not annotate a message.

Am I remembering correctly? Is there some way to get that feature back in Lion (without using MailTags, which won't sync across machines with my Gmail accounts)?

I never really cared about the feature but found a use for it just this week.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes and no
yes: it was possible to "annotate" mails with a todo - that function is gone in Lion

no: afaik it was not possible to "annotate" mails with a note as well

Comment: I think that must be what I was remembering. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You may be thinking of annotations in Preview.app.

As far as I could tell by looking at the Wikipedia history for Mail and the Ars Technica reviews for past Mac OS X releases, Mail has not had annotations. Unless you're talking about Notes, which alongside To Do's, where added in Version 3 of Mail in Leopard.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Well, by "annotation" I meant "a note that appeared connected to an individual message" instead of "a note that was an individual item unto itself."